# How to turn puts into a return?

Tags: ruby, return, output

```
puts "Hi"
=> "Hi"
```

Is there a way to get a return from this code such that I can say like:

```
x = puts "Hi"
```

The result of a puts is nil. I'm specifically interested in getting a return from the `%x()` but it seems likek the same concept applies to `puts`

Comment: So do you want a return from `puts` or `%x(...)` ? I don't see the point in getting something from `puts`, and `%x(...)` returns the output of the command. What exactly do you want to happen?

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to capture what is being printed on screen into a variable as the actual return is nil.

Comment: Sounds like you could just do `x = (expression)` then `puts x`.

Comment: x = (puts "derp") x is nil

Comment: `x = "derp"` (as zneak suggests)?

Comment: simply do something like x = p "Hello" and that will assign "Hello" to your x variable.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution if you don't want to write a custom function is to use `tap`, which is a neat little built-in method defined as

```
class Object
    def tap
        yield self
        self
    end
end
```

and is particularly useful for performing operations a newly created object, which is exactly what you're dealing with.  Here's how you'd use it in this case

```
x = "Hi".tap {|obj| puts obj}
```

When I need to do this a lot, I use a trivial little custom method I like to call "see", which quietly prints an object

```
class Object
    def see
        puts self
        self
    end
end
```

resulting in

```
x = "Hi".see
```

EDIT: Based on my sketchy knowledge of `%x`, I believe what you want is to get the source of a system command and execute it in one action.  In this case, you'll have to represent it as a string:

```
x = "destroy -device printer -reason rage".tap {|cmnd| %x{#{cmnd}}} # actually destroys printer
puts x # outputs "destroy -device printer -reason rage"
```

Comment: Can you re-phrase the answer with x%() in mind? I should have mentioned it in the OP. "Hi" already is "Hi" but x%(python \-\-version) returns nil and therefore tapping it also results in x being nil

Comment: `%x(...)` returns the **standard output** of a command as a string. Unfortunately, `$ python --version` writes to stderr, therefore `%x(python --version)` returns an empty string (not `nil`). Try `%x(python --version 2>&1)` the `2>&1` simply redirects stderr to stdout.

Comment: You may want to mention using 'p' rather than 'puts' to display the object as it is intended to be represented, for instance a string with the quotes around it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply do:

```
p x="hi"
```

If you want to remove the debugging, just remove two characters.

Comment: Yep, that is my recommendation.